# Is there a difference between Cmaj♭7 and Cdominant7 chords?

Tags: chord-theory

Is there a difference between Cmaj♭7 and Cdominant7 chords? As far as I can tell they are the same, is one used more commonly than the other?

Comment: FWIW, I have never seen those, only "C7". Where did you find such chord symbols?

Comment: They're simply not chord names as we know them! Dominant isn't often used, as a simple '7' assumes it's dominant.Check answers for 'What are MA7 and MI7 chords'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I’m very new to naming chords, “Cmajb7” was just something that stuck with me from a few years ago ‘cause it’s intuitive to me. But this advice has helped a lot :)

Comment: I don't understand downvoting of the question. The chord symbols are indeed wrong, but it doesn't make it a bad question, and the answer corrects the symbols.

Comment: @user1079505, I agree. I see too many downvotes apparently for no other reason than the OP posts a misunderstanding or has trouble wording the question. Questions are posted because the OP doesn't understand something. We have to read through the words and try to understand the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Technically they are the same thing BUT the spellings Cmaj♭7 and Cdominant7 are not used for chord symbols. if you want a chord that is spelled C-E-G-B♭ you simply write C7. That indicates Root, M3, P5 and m7. If you want C-E-G-B (M7) then you would write Cmaj7, although there are other ways to indicate a major 7th chord, such as ma7, M7 to name a couple.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with John's explanation, but I would like to point out one important thing, which is probably the cause of the misunderstanding in the question. The symbol `Cmajb7` is not only uncommon, but it is actually a contradiction in itself. The `maj` in the symbol `Cmaj7` does not refer to the quality of the triad but it refers to the seventh. So the correct parsing of `Cmaj7` is `C - maj7`, and not `Cmaj - 7`. I think the question only makes sense if one uses the latter parsing, because then it would make perfect sense to specify what kind of seventh should be added on top of the major triad. However, with the correct parsing - and this is of course just convention - the symbol `Cmajb7` is non-sensical, because it says: take a major triad `C` and add a major flat seventh `majb7`, which is of course impossible.

So the only common symbol for a C dominant seventh chord is `C7`, because it is understood that `7` stands for a minor seventh. If we want a major seventh, we need to use `maj7`, or, alternatively, any of the common symbols that indicate a major seventh chord, such as `CΔ7` or `CMa7`. I personally only use `CΔ7` and `Cmaj7` because they never cause misunderstandings.

Comment: A lucid explanation. There's lots of confusion with the numbers, but if we consider the number to be more related to the major or minor bit, it makes sense. That's until we encounter Cm6...!

Comment: @Tim: Thanks Tim. Yes, it's all about knowing the conventions, but actually Cm6 and Cmaj7 both makes sense in the same system, because we need 'm' to denote the minor triad, and we just use 'C' to denote the major triad. In that sense it's clear that the 'm' in Cm6 does not refer to the '6'  but to the basic triad.

Comment: Thanks for this answer (+1)  and pointing out the contradiction, something I should have done. @Tim makes a good point, I’ve wondered in the past why 7 was chosen to mean m7 in chord symbols myself since any other extension, 6, 9, 13 are all major unless flattened. Then again chord symbols are not always an exact science!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy: That's a good point. I guess nobody knows exactly why things developed that way, but I'd guess that a dominant seventh chord is just so much more common (in traditional folk music and conventional classical music), that it made sense to use a simple symbol for that only seventh chord that was used next to all the triads. Only when jazz started using seventh chords as basic harmonies did it become necessary to use other symbol in addition to '7', and '7' was already taken. When I started out I always used the mixolydian scale as the basis for understanding the naming of tensions.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - my guess is usage. By far the most common '7th' chord is dominant, so that gets the simplest label. But, do I feel a question coming on..?

Comment: @Tim and Matt, that was my thought too, you see a dominant chord much more than a maj7 in most styles of music.

Comment: Although only the 7th is different between C7 and CMaj7, and only the third is different between C7 and Cmin7  I still think it's simplest to say that the terms "Major" and "minor" in "CMaj7" and "Cmin7" describe *both* the third and seventh.  I would think writing CMaj7 followed by C7 makes the chord change clearer than CMaj7 followed by Cmaj♭7.  The latter notation might make the desired voice leading clearer, but if 7 and maj7 chords would normally place the 7th in different octaves [which could plausibly be the case with e.g. Fmaj7 and F7 when using standard tuning]...

Comment: ...that would usually because playing them in the same octave would be difficult.  An Fmaj 7 can put the 7th on top with --3210, or for some players 1-3210 or 113210, but playing an F7 with the seventh on top is apt to be difficult with standard tuning.

Comment: @supercat - nowhere mentions guitar, but playing using say, a barred open G shape, it's straightforward to drop the top string down a fret for maj7, then another fret for 7 (dom7). And - 113210 introduces  Bb. Why do we need that?

Answer (score 3):

The suffix *major* (Maj7) is referring to the 7th and not to the chord quality.

So there is only C7 (major chord with minor 7th) or Cmaj7 (major chord and major 7th)

But yes, the C7 can have different functions:

In classical music theory the C7 chord has the function of the dominant resolving to the tonic F.

In blues the C7 is the tonic (on C major) and is stable even it has a minor seventh (blue note - also the subdominant isn't notated as F b7 in the Blues and Jazz notation. F7 means here a minor 7th). In classic IV7  is corresponding to F Maj7 in Jazz.

But the symbol is the same - like others comments and answers say.

Comment: What would be the convention for naming C-Eb-G-Bb? If I understand correctly, Cmin7 would be C-E-G-Bb, C7

Comment: C-E-G-Bb is notated as C7 (=major third, minor seventh). Spelling C7 = dominant seventh chord. The chord symbol for C-Eb-G-Bb  is **Cm7** (Spelling:  **C minor seven** (minor third, the 7 is   minor too! but not specified  -  in contrary to the minor chord Cm with major 7th = Cm +7, in this case the seventh is clarified by a natural resp. a sharp sign.

Answer (score 1):

I think your intention is understood, and the chords would be the same, but you aren't following the chord symbol conventions.

It may help to understand the modifiers in chord symbols by adding parentheses which can be added to group the modifiers with the thing they modify. Normally parentheses will be added only to the chord extensions, but I will add them to all elements, just to illustrate...

> Cmaj♭7 and Cdominant7

`(Cmaj)(♭7)`

- Notice the `maj` modifies the root. The four triad types appended after the root letter: `maj`, 'min`,` aug`,` dim`. Depending on the notation system other symbols can be used, but they are still appended.
- the `♭` modifies the `7`, all the modifiers after the triad type are prefixed before the number

`(Cdominant)(7)`

The second chord is obviously meant to mean `C` dominant seventh chord. But, is the modifier 'dominant' for the triad `(Cdominant)(7)` or the seventh `(C)(dominant7)`? The problem is `dominant` isn't a modifier for either a triad type or a simple interval. It's not a 'dominant' triad. The triad part is major. The interval of a seventh isn't 'dominant'. Technically it's a minor seventh. 'Dominant' refers to *the whole chord*. Again, the meaning is clear, but that isn't a modifier of only one part of the chord.

The default values of all the elements - the triad type and the extensions - are those of a dominant `V13` in a major key. Spelled in `C` major it would be `G B D F A C E`. In terms of intervals above the root it would be major third, perfect fifth, minor seventh, major ninth, perfect eleventh, major thirteenth.

That brings us back to...

`(Cmaj)(♭7)` where the `maj` is redundant, we know it by default. The `♭` is a bit tricky. Sevenths are minor by default, and in this chord symbols system `♭` means lower by half step, but surely you didn't mean to make a minor seventh a diminished seventh! I'm sure you meant it is lowering a major seventh to minor. But, as sevenths are minor by default, `♭7` is redundant too. You only need to write `C7`.

Watch out for some confusing points in chord symbols, like...

- `Cdim7` where `dim` could apply to both the triad and seventh
- sharp and flat modifiers used as shorthand for 'raised' or 'lowered' even when an accidental isn't used in the actual spelling like `Bmin7♭5` spelled `B D F A` with no flat.
- sharp isn't used to raise the minor seventh, `maj` or a `Δ` get used, parenthesis help readability with things like `Cmin(maj7)`
- alternate possibilities like `C7♯5` versus `Caug7` versus `C7alt` or `C7sus4` versus `C11`

Comment: 'Sevenths are minor by default'. That statement is unstable. Unless you mean ' any chord with a bare 7 means that 7th is m7'. It's only diminished 7ths that have that 7th dropped by a tone, which you know.

Comment: @Tim, I mean the number `7` means _minor seventh_, you need to add a modifier to the seven to get major seventh `maj7` or diminished seven `dim7`, or one of the other symbols like `Δ` or `o`. If you look at groupings like this... `Gm7` ...means `(Gm)7` not `G(m7)` that parenthetical grouping is made clear by a case like `(Gm)(Δ7)`. The `m` modifier mean minor _for the triad_ not the `7`. The `7` is understood to always be a minor seventh unless modified. I call that a default value.